# Change all quotation marks to html entity in wordpress?

Tags: html, wordpress

Is it possible to add a string or function to the functions.php in Wordpress so that if there is ever a " in a post, it converts it to `&quot;` - the html entity code for quote.

I found that if I am writing a post that includes some code I want to be copied, the default quotes that WordPress inserts are open and closed when I only need standard quotes.  I tried to research the issue online, but not much comes up in regards to text replacement with WordPress. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [esc_html](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_html), Wordpress' newer equivalent to htmspecialchars.